# Why is it so easy to decompile Java Code?

Tags: java, decompiling

So I've just realized how easy it is to decompile my Java code. I've been searching around the net and I can't seem to figure out *WHY* its so easy. Every time I google something like "Why can I decomilple `.class` files?" or "Why does Java decompile so easily", all I get is links to software that can easily deompile my code. So I turn to you StackOverflow: why is it that Java can be converted back to easlily readable source code while C++ and other languages aren't very friendly to decompiling?

Thanks

Comment: Because Java never really gets "compiled" the same way that C++ does. (at least not until the JIT kicks in)

Comment: If you want to make this harder, use a proper obfuscater like ZKM. Its control flow obfuscation will prevent any decompiler from being able to decompile your code; the user will first have to deob your code (which requires a high knowledge of ZKM and Byte code engineering).

Comment: But All classes couldn't be decompiled and all decompiled classes coun't be compiled back without modification.

Comment: I can't believe someone closed this post for the reason they stated.  Who monitors the monitors?  Lordy!

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Because Java byte-code is closer (more similar) to the source than assembly.

In particular, `.class` files include metadata for classnames, method names, field & parameter types, etc...
All a Java (or .Net) decompiler needs to do is look at the instructions in each method body, and turn them into the appropriate syntactic constructs.

By contrast, native languages like C++ do not include any metadata at all, so the decompiler needs to reconstruct *everything*.

Comment: Also, java bytecode is not optimized the way native code is, because java relies on the JITter to optimize the code at execution time.

Comment: As a side note to the point on metadata, it is especially true when the code is NOT directly from Java but other JVM languages.  Programming languages such as Kotlin (recommended by Google for Android) produces even more metadata, for instance via the `Instrinsics.checkNotNull` method will contain field name as its string parameter which will not be touched by most obfuscators.

Comment: *It is possible to configure obfuscators and the Kotlin compiler to drop these checks but most companies did NOT do it.  IMO, it is also NOT very useful to do so.  It does NOT add much difficulty to RE, as compared to unobfuscated vs obfuscated code.  Time is probably better spent on moving critical component to server side with authentication if RE is really unwanted.

Answer (score 24):

Java is compiled into an intermediate form, JVM bytecode, that retains a large amount of the information contained in the original Java code.  A language like C++ compiles into assembly code, with looks a lot different from the original code, and is, therefore, harder to reverse.

Comment: +1. So the point is bytecode, not Java. Java can be compiled into x86 instructions (http://www.excelsior-usa.com/jet.html, http://gcc.gnu.org/java/), and then be as hard to decompile as C++.

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov if the resulting code still allows reflection to work, it will still be easier than C++ to decompile, because that keeps a lot of metadata around.

Comment: @Dave: that's true for method-/class-level information, the actual *instructions inside* the methods will be harder to decompile than `.class` files.